# How would the following C++ code be written as a java class file(named Monstor)

Tags: java, c++

```
#ifndef MONSTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define MONSTOR_H_INCLUDED
#include "Player.h"


class Monstor : public Creature
{
public:
enum Type
{
    DRAGON,
    ORC,
    SLIME,
    MAX_TYPES
};
struct MonstorData
{
    const char *name;
    char symbol;
    int health;
    int damage;
    int gold;
};

static MonstorData monstorData[Monstor::MAX_TYPES];

Monstor(Type type):
    Creature(monstorData[type].name, monstorData[type].symbol, monstorData[type].health, monstorData[type].damage, monstorData[type].gold)
{
}

static int getRandomNumber( int min, int max)
{
    static const double fraction = 1.0 / (static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
    return static_cast<int>(rand() * fraction * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

static Monstor getRandomMonstor()
{
    int temp = getRandomNumber(0, MAX_TYPES - 1);

    return Monstor(static_cast<Type>(temp));
}
void levelUp()
{
    m_damage++;
}
};

Monstor::MonstorData Monstor::monstorData[Monstor::MAX_TYPES]
{
{"dragon", 'D', 20, 10, 100},
{"orc", 'o', 4, 5, 25},
{"slime", 's', 1, 3, 10}
};
//Monstor::monstorData[0].damage++;


#endif // MONSTOR_H_INCLUDED
```

the thing thats challenging me the most is Struct array, and the enum types
so far i have made a class named Monster, which extends Creature, but creature needs a name passed as a parameter which is obtained from the enum array at the bottom.

Please help

This is my attempt below, I am getting an error on monsterData[0], [1],[2]

```
class MonsterData {
String name;
char symbol;
int health;
int damage;
int gold;
MonsterData(String name, char symbol, int health, int damage, int gold){
    this.name=name;
    this.symbol=symbol;
    this.health=health;
    this.damage=damage;
    this.gold=gold;
}
```

}

```
public class Monstor extends Creature {
public enum Type{
    DRAGON("0"),
    ORC("1"),
    SLIME("2"),
    MAX_TYPES("3");

    private String value;

    Type(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}

   public MonsterData[] monsterData = new MonsterData[Integer.parseInt(Type.MAX_TYPES.toString())];

   monsterData[0] = new MonsterData("Dragon", 'D', 20, 10, 100);
    monsterData[1] = new MonsterData("orc", 'O', 4, 5, 25);
    monsterData[2] = new MonsterData("slime", 'S', 1, 3, 10);
```

Comment: Don't try to cut-n-paste a C++ solution into Java. Instead understand the behaviour that the C++ code describes and re-implement it in Java using Java best practices, libraries, and idioms. The alternative is to have code that, if it runs, runs poorly. Show the Java code you have so far so that people know where you're at and how best to guide you to a worthwhile solution.

Comment: I have made a monstor class, which extends creature, and i have also made a class MonstorData. The thing that's confusing me is how to make an array of MonstorData to hold the multiple monstors, and how to pass the enum to super(), cause super() needs the name, symbol, damage, health and gold of the MonstorData array

Comment: Don't describe code. Show it. It's much more efficient and removes all sorts of potential questions like, "Does this guy seriously expect us to write the code for him?"

Comment: Ive uploaded my edit(attempt at the java code), the array is the only difficulty im currently facing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are making a separate Monstor class and MonstorData class / struct in either C++ or in Java.  The whole point of object oriented programming is that you encapsulate both data and behavior in the same class.

Java has enums that look like C++ ones, perhaps needing an additional semi-colon, but if you define them inside another class like that you want to make them static.

In Java, you can have an array of classes, but using a Collection is typically better.  However, in java, the array does not contain the whole object, just a null reference to the object.  So, to define the array, you still need to call new.

```
class Thing {
    private int intVal;
    private String name;
    public Thing(String name, int intVal) {
        this.name = name;
        this.intVal = intVal;
    }

    private static Thing[] theThings{
        new Thing("Thing 1", 1), 
        new Thing("Thing 2", 2)
    }
}
```